# stanford nlp pos tagging

Tags: java, maven, nlp, stanford-nlp

Im doing my POS (part of speech tagging) from this tagger. But when i combine that part to my maven project it doesnt work. Is there a way where i can user stanford directly to do pos without using a seperate tagger? I want the output as same as this.

```
 MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
        String sample = "Im so happy about my marks";
        String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);
        System.out.println(tagged);
```

output:Im/NNP so/RB happy/JJ about/IN my/PRP$ marks/NNS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course Stanford CoreNLP can do tagging directly. The following lines of code tag your example, and give you the desired output.

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos");

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Annotation annotation = new Annotation("I'm so happy about my marks");
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
    for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class);
        // this is the POS tag of the token
        String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println(word + "/" + pos);
    }
}
```